# Client code "randomly" fails whenever it tries to create GzipInputstream

Tags: java, tcp, java-io, gzipinputstream

I have a server that basically caters to multiple clients.
I am basically using gzip(input/output)stream to compress the data between client-server.

Many clients can send the requests to server at the same time and hence I have a thread to cater to each client.

Now, the problem that I am experiencing is that "randomly" some client code fails whenever it tries to execute following after the connection to the server has been established.

```
GZIPInputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(server.getInputStream());
```

I get `java.io.EOFException`.

And when I say randomly, I mean there is no pattern that I can find in the exception.
The requests are being send properly (else it would not work for any client requests).

I have searched a lot..but couldn't find anything.. :(

Any pointers on the above problem?

```
Socket connection= new Socket("localhost",2428);
GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(url.getBytes());
out.finish();
GZIPInputStream in=null;

try {
    in = new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream(),1024); // Exception raised here
} catch(Exception e) { }
```

Server code that accepts a new connection and spawns a new thread.

```
ServerSocket dsWeb= new ServerSocket(2428);
Socket webClient;
while(true){
webClient = dsWeb.accept();

executor.execute(new ThreadPool()); // each request to be handled by a separate thread
```

The code within the thread ..

```
GZIPInputStream inWeb = new GZIPInputStream(webClient.getInputStream());
int c1=0;
byte[] b1 = new byte[100000];
c1=inWeb.read(b1);
//Process the request
GZIPOutputStream outWeb = new GZIPOutputStream(webClient.getOutputStream());
outWeb.write(/* Response */);
outWeb.finish();
```

Here's the stacktrace of the exception I get:

```
java.io.EOFException at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.WebServerVNCRequest.doGet(WebServerVNCRequest.java:78)
```

Comment: the problem tat i presume could be is tat when we instantiate the GZIPinputstream object as shown in http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.java.htm the stream is read and EOF is thrown if it reads a -1. Since, there is a single Server inputstream for clients to access, the character read as -1 is owing to the previous read() action done. Does the above sound plausible ??

Comment: `InputStream.read()` will return -1 when there's no more data in the stream, so that's still the symptom not the root cause.

Comment: What happens if you remove the gzip code?

Comment: Post a more complete code example... the use of `webClient` between your socket-accept loop and the code which runs in the separate thread is murky.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error rate?  Could it be that these are random (occasional) network errors?  Or perhaps your server is occasionally experiencing an internal error?

It doesn't really sound like the problem is with the GZip data itself, but rather with an occasional network break.  My guess is that your server occasionally generates an exception and sends an invalid stream, causing this type of error on the client.  Perhaps try logging all exceptions on the server to insure that you aren't occasionally getting internal failure there?

Comment: hi,

i doubt if the network is an issue becauuse for now , client-server app run on the same machine( for testing purposes).
If i try reading from a BufferedInputStream, then i find none of these errors..

The main reason i chose to compress the data is because i have around 130KBs of data that has to be exchanged between the client-server, and using BufferedInputStream, i wwas able to read only partially.. :( !!

insights on the above ?

Comment: If the type of stream matters, then there must be some odd bug in the code.  Is there any way to post the code that causes the issue?

Comment: Heres the stacktrace of the exception i get..

java.io.EOFException
 at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.WebServerVNCRequest.doGet(WebServerVNCRequest.java:78)

Comment: A TCP network break will not cause an EOFException. Neither will an 'invalid stream'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `webClient` isn't passed to `new ThreadPool()`. This can only mean that it is an instance member of the class, which introduces a thread-safety problem. Make it a local variable and pass it explicitly to the `Runnable` that handles it.

NB your reading code is unduly optimistic. You won't get the entire request Ina single read. You have to loop. A buffer size of 100Kb is just wasted space: you won't get anywhere near that in a single read, even after dezipping.

Comment: But, `webClient` is a local variable.

Comment: Hold on, maybe not?

Comment: No real evidence of that, and the code wouldn't compile, as it would need to be final to be available to `new ThreadPool()`, and if it was final it couldn't be reassigned. Or else this isn't the real code, in which case the question is futile and should be closed.